# Libre Office Calc Data Range Source empty

Tags: mysql, libreoffice-calc

I have a table in MySQL (really is a "View") that I changed the Name. It was used in a Calc spreadsheet Control (Text box and clicked on it) to update some cell contents. After the Name change Calc control does not work. I searched Internet, played with Calc all day and could not a fix so far. Basically, in "Define Database Range" window the "Source" section on the bottom is empty, and it is not editable. The macro runs without error but produces nothing. Why is the "Source" empty, and how to set it up to the proper source?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out - maybe not the best solution.

1. Data>Define range>Select the range with problem (source missing for some reason)
2. Data>Define range: recreate the same range with desired name
3. `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F4` will open up Mysql data source; select the desired table or query; content will appear in the top right window
4. Click on the top left corner of the output table; Data-to-text icon will appear in row above
5. Click on Data-to-text icon and the table will be inserted into the active range in the spreadsheet
6. Now the `Data>Define range` selected range will have the proper SOURCE filled in as the data source of the range

Last, I had to recreate the macro that is assigned to the Text box Control. The macro is `Data>Select Range` + `Data>Refresh Range` + whatever else...

Now my original method of clicking on the text box to refresh data in the spreadsheet from MySQL works again!